# Can I speed up my membership requests to Play! Framework Google Group?

Tags: playframework

I posted a few posts [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework) a few days ago, but my posts were not approved yet.

Who are the moderators? Can I speed up the process of being approved?

I just want to make sure that my membership request isn't lost in some sea of email.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speeding up a membership request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you post via web? I use e-mail and they appear instantly.

Comment: I posted via the web interface, and it said my post is waiting moderation. I don't think this is a bug in Google-groups ... but I'll try emailing them.

Comment: I mean I post directly to the group, via e-mail, and these posts show up immediately.

Comment: And the Play guys were at Devoxx last week so I guess they didn't have the time to approve your posts.

Comment: Hmm, my post just showed up immediately now. So I guess only the web interface is moderated for some reason ??? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/1-e_gkpzCxE

Comment: Oddly enough, my older posts now appear in the group. They may have appeared back then, because I see responses from 2 days ago - I didn't get any email about these responses, even though I asked to be notified when someone posts a reply.

Comment: I have similar issues. Although I posted numerous times and I have been a member for a few month, every so often I get the "Posts for new members are moderated". Could be a google groups issue.